# How to display all values in a dictionary when the value is a class type

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary that I am trying to display all values from. The issue with the answers I have found is that they only return the key and the value. My value is a type I made within my repository.

1. Below is my dictionary. My value is my Badge class with multiple properties:

```
public class BadgesRepository
{
    private Dictionary<int, Badge> badgeDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Badge>();
    public void AddBadgeDictionaryEntry(int badgeID, Badge newBadge)
    {
        badgeDictionary.Add(badgeID, newBadge);
    }
}
```

2. Below is my Badge class :

```
public class Badge
{
    public int BadgeID { get; set; }
    public string BadgeName { get; set; }
    public List<string> DoorList { get; set; }
}
```

3. Here I'd like to display all values of the Dictionary:

```
private void ViewAllBadges()
{
    Console.WriteLine("All badge data is listed below: ");
    Dictionary<int, Badge>.ValueCollection values = 
    foreach (Badge val in values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Badge ID: {0}", val);
    }
}
```

Comment: Dictionary.Values would be what you need.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.values?view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2_Values

Comment: All you need is a ToString method for your Badge class, methinks. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method

Comment: You now have 3 [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If any were useful, [upvote them](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up). If one solved your problem, [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). (Hit the checkmark.)

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a ToString method for your Badge class, methinks. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method.
Based on their Example:

```
class Person
{
    public int BadgeID { get; set; }
    public string BadgeName { get; set; }
    public List<string> DoorList { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return BadgeID.ToString() + " " + 
               BadgeName + " "+
               String.Join(", ", DoorList.ToArray()); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override ToString() inside Badge class as roadrunner66's mentioned

Then

```
foreach (var item in badgeDictionary)
{
    Badge badge = item.Value;
    Console.WriteLine(badge.ToString());
}
```

Or

```
foreach (var item in badgeDictionary)
{
    Badge badge = item.Value;

    Console.WriteLine("Badge ID: {0} BadgeName {1} DoorList {2}", badge.BadgeID, badge.BadgeName, String.Join(", ", badge.DoorList.ToArray()));
}
```

( Code above is just idea, I'm not try to build this code yet, so maybe error build. )

Answer (score 0):

> ```cs
> private void ViewAllBadges()
> {
>    Console.WriteLine("All badge data is listed below: ");
>    Dictionary<int, Badge>.ValueCollection values = 
>    foreach (Badge val in values)
>    {
>        Console.WriteLine("Badge ID: {0}", val);
>    }
> }
> ```

### Looks like you want to use the [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.Values`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.values?view=netcore-3.1) property.

Add the `ViewAllBadges` method to your `BadgesRepository` class. Note the `.Values` property in the `foreach` loop:

```cs
public class BadgesRepository
{
    private Dictionary<int, Badge> badgeDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Badge>();

    public void AddBadgeDictionaryEntry(int badgeID, Badge newBadge)
    {
        badgeDictionary.Add(badgeID, newBadge);
    }

    public void ViewAllBadges()
    {
        foreach (Badge badge in badgeDictionary.Values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                $"Badge ID: {badge.BadgeID}, " +
                $"Badge name: {badge.BadgeName}, " +
                $"Door list: {string.Join(", ", badge.DoorList)}");
        }
    }
}
```

You can also [override `ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method) in your `Badges` class as others have suggested...

```cs
public class Badge
{
    public int BadgeID { get; set; }
    public string BadgeName { get; set; }
    public List<string> DoorList { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Badge ID: {BadgeID}, " +
                $"Badge name: {BadgeName}, " +
                $"Door list: {string.Join(", ", DoorList)}";
    }
}
```

...and simplify the `ViewAllBadges()` method:

```cs
public void ViewAllBadges()
{
    foreach (Badge badge in badgeDictionary.Values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(badge.ToString());
    }
}
```

Here's an example calling code:

```cs
var bd = new BadgesRepository();

var badge1 = new Badge();
badge1.BadgeID = 1;
badge1.BadgeName = "One";
badge1.DoorList = new List<string>() { "Door 1", "Door 100" };
bd.AddBadgeDictionaryEntry(1, badge1);

var badge2 = new Badge();
badge2.BadgeID = 2;
badge2.BadgeName = "Two";
badge2.DoorList = new List<string>() { "Door 2", "Door 200" };
bd.AddBadgeDictionaryEntry(2, badge2);

var badge3= new Badge();
badge3.BadgeID = 3;
badge3.BadgeName = "Three";
badge3.DoorList = new List<string>() { "Door 3", "Door 300" };
bd.AddBadgeDictionaryEntry(3, badge3);

bd.ViewAllBadges();
```